# plot coordinates line in a pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I have a scatter plot. I would like to plot coordinate lines for each point, from X to Y, just like we used to do on school.

See picture below as a reference.

[image]

I ended up using the "grid()" property, but that is not exactly what I want.

I also tried to use "axhline" and "axvline" passing xmin, xmax and ymin, ymax, but it did not work. It crossed a line throughout the entire plot.

Have a great day!

Comment: `vlines` and `hlines` maybe?

Comment: You can loop over your points (x,y) and plot the lines yourself: `plt.plot([x, 0], [x, y])` and `plt.plot([0, y], [x, y])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`vlines`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.vlines.html) to draw the vertical lines and [`hlines`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hlines.html) to draw the horizontal lines. These are different from [`axvline`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axvline.html) and [`axhline`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axhline.html), since those functions take values between 0 and 1 while `vlines` and `hlines` work in the data coordinates. I pass `vlines` the `y.min()` as `ymin` so it doesn't go too low and I pass `hlines` the `x.min()` as `xmin` so it doesn't go too far to the left. I also adjusted the `zorder` of the scatter plot so the lines are behind the points.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
x = np.arange(2009, 2024)
y = rng.random(x.size)*13

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y, zorder=3)
ax.vlines(x, y.min(), y, color="r", linewidth=0.5)
ax.hlines(y, x.min(), x, color="r", linewidth=0.5)
fig.show()
```

[image]